# Drawing a specific region of a 3D scene to a larger canvas/viewport

Tags: c#, math, matrix, sharpdx

I have a 3D scene of which I want to draw a specific region onto a larger canvas/viewport (think like a magnifying glass).

Something like the following image:
[image: Zoom in on part of an existing 3D scene]

I want to maintain any perspective effects, simply moving my camera to the specified region wouldn't give that effect.

I gathered from http://www.mvps.org/DirectX/articles/tilerender/index.htm that it's possible to do some trickery with the Projection Matrix but I couldn't figure out the math behind getting a more specific subsection/region than what is described in that article.

If we assume the coordinates described in the article, x0y0 would be the exact center of the scene, x-1y1 would be the top-left and x1y-1 would be the bottom-right of the scene.

I would, for example, want to render the region ranging from x-0.75y0.75 to x-0.25y0.25.

I have a Projection matrix and a View matrix separately available. I am using the SharpDX library and my Projection matrix is Right-Handed(which seems the flip the y-coordinates described above).

How do I calculate the Scale/Translation matrices that I need to multiply my Projection matrix with? Or, alternatively, what other ways are there to tackle this issue?

Psuedo-code would be something like this:

```
public Matrix GetProjectionRegion(float topLeftX, float topLeftY, float bottomRightX, float bottomRightY)
{
    var magicMatrix = Matrix.Identity;;
    //some magic
    return magicMatrix;
}
ProjectionMatrix *= GetProjectionRegion(-0.75f, 0.75f, -0.25f, 0.25f);
```

**EDIT:**
I am currently creating my Projection matrix using one of two methods:

```
ProjectionMatrix = Matrix.PerspectiveFovRH(FOV, Width / Height, NearPlane, FarPlane);
```

or

```
ProjectionMatrix = Matrix.OrthoOffCenterRH(_topLeft.X, _bottomRight.X, _topLeft.Y, _bottomRight.Y, NearPlane, FarPlane);
```

Nearplane is 75 farplane is 5000000; Width/Height/_topLeft/_topRight are all pixel formats as far as I remember.

The matrices are used Row-Major.

Comment: @Rabbid76 see edit, though I don't think the way the projection matrix is created should matter too much. Matrices are used Row-Major

Comment: I will try that tomorrow, not quite what I had in mind but something I can work with, assuming it works like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do a very basic mechanism for zooming in, you could cheat with your camera matrix, that is the "World" in your world view projection matrix.

The zoom could be tackled through proximity to the location.  Nothing more.  BUT, if you are determined, you could also scale that World matrix also, which would then enlarge all objects, therefore effectively zoom.

Comment: Scaling the Projection matrix also effectively zooms, but it's based around the center. All I need after that is to translate it correctly. This is described in the linked article.

Comment: Agree. Would expect that the camera direction would be determined prior scale.